# How can we evaluate $S_{N}=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\sin^2\left({x\over 2k}\right)?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometric-series

I am interested in evaluating the sum of:

$$S_{N}=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\sin^2\left({x\over 2k}\right)\tag1$$

Expanded $(1)$

$$\sin^2\left({x\over 2}\right)+\sin^2\left({x\over 4}\right)+\sin^2\left({x\over 6}\right)+\cdots+\sin^2\left({x\over 2N}\right)\tag2$$

Using $$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$$

$$S_{N}=N-\sum_{k=1}^{N}\cos^2\left({x\over 2k}\right)\tag3$$

Using $$\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)=\cos(2x)$$

$(1)$+$(3)\implies$

$$2S_{N}=N-\sum_{k=1}^{N}\cos\left({x\over k}\right)\tag4$$

Recall $${1\over 2}+\sum_{k=1}^{N}\cos(kx)={\sin(N+1/2)x\over 2\sin(x/2)}\tag5$$

$$\cos(A)-\cos(B)=2\sin\left({A+B\over 2}\right)\sin\left({A-B\over 2}\right)\tag6$$

$$\cos(kx)-\cos\left({x\over k}\right)=2\sin\left[x\left({k^2+1\over 2k}\right)\right]\sin\left[x\left({k^2-1\over 2k}\right)\right]\tag7$$

$(4)$+$(5)\implies$

$$2S_{N}+{\sin(N+1/2)x\over 2\sin(x/2)}=N+{1\over 2}+2\sum_{k=1}^{N}\sin\left[x\left({k^2+1\over 2k}\right)\right]\sin\left[x\left({k^2-1\over 2k}\right)\right]\tag8$$

How can we evaluate $(1)?$

Comment: you probably won't find a close form for the expression

Comment: This will imply that we have a general formula for 

$$S_N(x) = \sum_{k=1}^N \sqrt[k]{x}$$